# setValueAsync (Cannot resolve method 'setValueAsync' in 'DatabaseReference')

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-platform

I am doing this guide [link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/save-data#section-set) and i cant call setValueAsync i get error Cannot resolve method 'setValueAsync' in 'DatabaseReference'. I saw that I can use it at the start where I set String but I don't know how can it help me. Thanks all.

My code:

```
public class MessageMembersList extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {
    private Button btnConnectToServer;
    FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    FirebaseUser user;
    String curentName;
    String curentLastName;
    String curentEmail;
    String Name;
    String LastName;
    String Email;

    public Users(String Name, String LastName, String Email) {

        this.Name = Name;
        this.LastName = LastName;
        this.Email = Email;

    }

    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        btnConnectToServer = (Button) getView().findViewById(R.id.btnConnectToServer);
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        btnConnectToServer.setOnClickListener(this);
        user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();

                    FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
                    DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference().child("No server").child(user.getUid());
                    myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot datasnapshot) {
                            curentName = (String) datasnapshot.child("name").getValue().toString();
                            curentLastName = (String) datasnapshot.child("lastName").getValue().toString();
                            curentEmail = (String) datasnapshot.child("email").getValue().toString();

                            txt1.setText(Name);

                        }


                        @Override
                        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

                        }
                    });
}
}
```

Error part setValueAsync (Cannot resolve method 'setValueAsync' in 'DatabaseReference').
Users have an error to but i am not gona talk about it in this question.

```
 @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        switch (view.getId()){
            case R.id.btnConnectToServer:
                connectedToServer = false;
                        WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) getActivity().getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
                        WifiInfo info = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo();
                        String ssid = info.getSSID();
                        serverName = ssid;

                        FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
                        DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference().child(ssid);

                        myRef.child(user.getUid()).setValueAsync(new Users(curentName,curentLastName,curentEmail));

                        break;
                    }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `setValueAsync()` method is a part of the [Firebase Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/save-data#section-set) and does **not** work in Android. If you need to add a value to the Realtime Database in an Android fragment, you have to use the Fireabse Android SDK and use `setValue()` method as explained in the official documentation for [writing data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#basic_write).

Comment: But if i use setValue() i get a random name for value. like -MzxnO08F4QyQTYlsBDG: Tom but i want Name: Tom

Comment: No, if you are using [push()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/DatabaseReference#push()), you're getting a random value. If don't want that, then simply use `ref.child("Name").setValue("Tom")`, right?